# How can I SELECT data which in Arabic language in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wampserver

the following doesn't works, how can I search in data which stored in Arabic

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name` LIKE = "%شريف%"
```

that gave me Error sql query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name` LIKE "%شريف%"
```

Comment: Yup. Also, while you can use "double quotes" for string literals in MySQL, I'd recommend using the more ANSI-standard 'single quotes', which will work in MySQL and also with a broader variety of other database systems.

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with the language or character set being used. It's a simple syntax error.

To put it simply, don't use `LIKE` and `=` together. Use one or the other. I guess you mean `LIKE` in this case, so remove the `=` and your query will work.

Answer (score 0):

In your query you don't write = operator or LIKE keyword at a same time

> 1. If you want to use LIKE keyword then follow the below query

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name` LIKE "%شريف%"
```

> 2. If you want to use = operator then follow the below query

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name` = "شريف"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command for searching Arabic data use:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE  MATCH(`name`) AGAINST('شريف' in Boolean Mode);
```